# How to configure GC to not stop the world?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm

Suppose I have a `JVM` 1.7, which runs normally with 1G max. heap size. and uses only ~0.5G of heap.

At some moment the heap usage steeply increased in few minutes (I suspect increased load not a memory leak) and GC (`PS MarkSweep`) started. The GC was running for about *30 min.* and the server did not respond all that time.

The heap stats shows that at that moment `Old Gen` heap usage increased, `Eden` decreased, and *max* `Survivor` increased too.

The JVM uses default option `-XX:+UseParallelGC`

I will try to increase the heap, limit the input data size, etc. However I wonder how I can tune the GC to *not* "stop the world" for half an hour. I don't mind if the server slows down but I do not want it to stop responding at all.

How to configure GC to not *stop the world* ?

Comment: I presume that you're using Oracle VM and at the moment we don't have pause less GC collectors unlike commercial VMs like Azul's Zing :) but still 30 mins for a GC pause is not likely to happen for a 1G heap. How are you measuring your GC running times ? Are you setting any VM flags while starting your application ?

Comment: It is Oracle VM. I measured the GC time with an internal monitoring tool. No additional VM flags was added.

Comment: just a random check, does your code have lot of finalizers in it ? :)

Comment: GC will not be usually that long for heaps of 1gb. is it possible to add the output of the tool you used to conclude that GC is taking 30 mins ? did you see the frequency of GCs ? May be you don't have a single GC that's taking 30 mins but you have too many small GCs :) I suggest you enable GC logs in your application to get a better insight

Comment: Thank you. Enabling GC log sounds like a good idea. I should probably add `-Xloggc:logs/gc.log`

Comment: I suggest you add these flags as well `-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps 
-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-Xloggc:logs-dir-path/gc.log` to get more details about heap usages and tenuring info at the time of GC :)

Comment: Thanks again. I will do it.

Comment: These 30 minutes sound too unbelievable as the GC should do some tens of MB/s. Check for swapping or an alike problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can't have guarantees (unless you are on VM like Zing) you can give soft goals to GC which it will try to achieve. See more here.
[Oracle Technetwork. pt. Ergonomics](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html)

> **XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=**.This is interpreted as a hint that pause times of  milliseconds or less are desired; ... Note that these adjustments may cause the garbage collector to reduce the overall throughput of the application and in some cases the desired pause time goal cannot be met.
>
> **-XX:GCTimeRatio=**.The throughput goal is measured in terms of the time spent doing garbage collection vs. the time spent outside of garbage collection (referred to as application time). The goal is specified by the command line option -XX:GCTimeRatio=, which sets the ratio of garbage collection time to application time to 1 / (1 + ). For example, -XX:GCTimeRatio=19 sets a goal of 1/20 or 5% of the total time in garbage collection. The default value is 99, resulting in a goal of 1% of the time in garbage collection.

PS. However, I have an opinion that if an app with 0.5Gb heap spends 30 minutes in GC there are more chances that there's something wrong with the app, not with GC itself unless you are trying to run the app on some legacy platform.