# How to prevent ParNew to stop application for a few minutes

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm

One day my application got stuck for a `~5 min`. I believe it happened  because of `ParNew` GC. I don't have GC logs but the internal tool shows that `ParNew` consumed `~35% CPU` at that time. Now I wonder how to prevent that in future.

The application runs with `JDK 1.8` and `2.5G` heap. The GC options are `XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode`.

I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577993/how-to-configure-gc-to-not-stop-the-world) I can use `XX:MaxGCPauseMillis` and `XX:GCTimeRatio`. What else would you propose to prevent `ParNew` from stopping the application for a few minutes ?

Comment: you should provide gc-logs covering the time span of interest.

Answer (score 1):

GC is optimized not to eat your cpu time, being stuck for 5 minutes is far from normal, either you released millions of objects or most likely your allocated almost (if not all) your heap space, forcing the GC to retrieve every piece of memory it could find. I would also check for  memory leaks.